# Reading off annotations of MKMapViews in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to find the coordinates of an annotation in many MKMapViews in this way:

```
NSMutableArray *latitudes = [NSMutableArray array];

for (MKMapView *map in MapViewArray)
{
  NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [map.annotations lastObject].coordinate.latitude];                       
  [latitudes addObject: latitude];
}

NSMutableArray *longitudes = [NSMutableArray array];

for (MKMapView *map in MapViewArray)
{
     NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [map.annotations lastObject].coordinate.latitude];


    [longitudes addObject: longitude];
}
```

This code though gives me this error:

```
property 'coordinate' not found on object of type id
```

How can I solve it??

The map views in the array are of this type:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView2;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify the MKAnnotation protocol to make it compile:

```
NSMutableArray *latitudes = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray *longitudes = [NSMutableArray array];

for (MKMapView *map in MapViewArray)
{
    id<MKAnnotation> annotation = [map.annotations lastObject];
    NSString *latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", annotation.coordinate.latitude];                       
    NSString *longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", annotation.coordinate.latitude];        
    [longitudes addObject: longitude];
    [latitudes addObject: latitude];
}
```

Also I optimized your code to use only one loop.