# how can I get displayed titles of annotation in MKMapview?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, mapkitannotation

I have displayed multiple annotations with titles on MKMapView, How can I get the title of annotations in an array which are displayed on MkMapView ?

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
 for (MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views) {
 NSMutableArray *annotationsTitles=[[NSMutableArray]];
 [annotationsTitles addObject:annotationView.annotation.title]
 annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
}
```

I tried the below code unable to get the exact array.

Answer (score 0):

its not exactly same but u can get how to do that from these..

[Reading off annotations of MKMapViews in NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207875/reading-off-annotations-of-mkmapviews-in-nsarray?rq=1)